# How to pass a value to anther page throug ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

In my project, I want to pass a value trVwId in 3.php to stSId of hidden input in 1.php page.

The  content of cenDiv is from 2.php, Main code of 1.php is:

```
<script>
    $.ajax({
        ......
        url:"2.php",
        success:function(data)
        {
            $("#cenDiv").html(data);
            $.parser.parse($('#corWSId').parent());
        }
      });
</script>
<div id="cenDiv"></div>
<div class="easyui-panel" id="p4" >
 <input type="hidden" id="stSId" value="" name="stSN"> 
</div>
```

And then I clicked a button, content of cenDiv is changed which is from 3.php. The main code of 2.php is:

```
echo '
<div ><table >  </table></div>

<script>
      .......
      $.ajax({
        .......
        url:"3.php",
        success:function(data)
         {
            $("#cenDiv").html(data);
            $.parser.parse($(\'#dvcId\').parent());
         }
       });  

    function transmitDoc()
    {
    t1=$("#trVwId").val();//works OK
    $("#stSId").value=t1;//fail
    t2=$("#stSId").val();
    alert(t1);//works OK
    alert(t2);//fail
   }
 </script>
 ';
```

The main code of 3.php is：

```
 <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="easyui-linkbutton" onclick="transmitDoc()">tranSmit</a>
<input type="text" id="trVwId" style="width:99%;height:100px" name=""/>
```

Now, the value of trVwId in 3.php should be passed to stSId in 1.php through transmitDoc() method.

I found that t1=$("#trVwId").val(); works OK, but $("#stSId").value=t1 work fail. Actually, 1.php has been loaded, and stSId id should be in DOM.

It seems nothing wrong, Who can help me?